# change background of special item in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a List View and I want to change background of 33rd item(it is an example) of list view My list view  is not clickable and is not manual scroll-able 
and I Control my list view's scroll 
I see many Posts In This site but don't get my answer

Comment: do proper searching. lots of answer are available. otherwise put code of snippet whatever you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a custom listview adapter. For eg,

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if(position==33){
             //change background code here
        }
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Here the position means position of the list item. For more details using custom listview adapter see here @ http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thanks.